# GWT RequestFactory: check if members have been set without permission

Tags: gwt, requestfactory

I am working with GWT / RequestFactory and a set of customer requirements regarding permissions. Let me explain a basic example:

Every user is assigned to a company. Every user should be able to edit company's core data - but only e.g contact information, website etc. Security-relevant ones like BIC/SWIFT, IBAN, Company name and so on can only be changed if the user has a certain permission XY.

So far so good, on the client side I can check the permissions and disable those fields the user is not allowed to edit. But what would be the most elegant way to ensure on the server side that those fields have not been set without permission?

My problem is that I cannot track changes on the server side. Having @PreAuthorize on every setter is not an option too, because it would end in an authorization-massacre in each and every entity.

At the moment I am following a workaround: every field that is secured / depends on a given permission is passed as an argument to the entity-method and is excluded from the proxy. That way, values cannot be set using the proxy and I can check in my server code if the user has permissions. If not, nothing happens. If user has permissions, I set the values manually. But that produces a lot of boilerplate-code and ugly method signatures because the number of values passed to the method could get large.

I hope you understand my issue. I'm looking forward for your opinions and tips. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can receive many answers (different each other), and all of them could be right, so, at the end is your call. Wait for others answers. I am going to give you the approach that I followed (and it worked pretty well). :D.

Under my opinion, the server should do less as possible, so keep the logic for allowing modify each param on the server I think it is not a scalable solution (*if your system has 1M users modifying everything at the same time, will your server work fluent?*). I prefer let the client do the job (like Roomba :D).

For solving that problem, in our system we implemented an Access Control List solution. You can store in your db, on each user entity, a list with granted permissions. So, when that information arrives to the client (after user's log in, for example), you can get them, and show the fields that he/she is allow to modify.

Something like:

```
if (canModifyPersonalDetails(user.getAcls(), ...) ) {
   //show labels ...
}

if (canModifyBankDetails(user.getAcls(), ...) ) {
  //show labels
}
```

You can not avoid server call for log in, so it is not a big deal send the extra information (think about the ACLs could be simple list of integers 0 means personal details, 1 bank details....).

If you are dealing with very compromised information and you prefer do some stuff on the server, in that case probably I'd set up a security level, when you are persisting/updating your proxy, I'd do something like:

```
if (isAllowForPersonalDetails(user.getSecurityCode()) {
   //update the modified personal details
}

if (isAllowForBankDetails(user.getSecurityCode()) {
   //update the modified bank details
}

user.update();
```

I am a big fan of clear User GUI's, and a very big fan of let the server free as much as possible, so I prefer the first option. But if you have constraints for modifying user entity in db, or you prefer do not modify your views, or any constraint with security, maybe the second option is the best one for you.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for your answer so far. If I understood your solution correctly, you do not do any security checks on the server side? My problem is that I cannot trust client data that is submitted to the server (and normally you never should!). What if a request is faked with tools like BURP? Because you disable/hide fields in the UI that does not necessarily mean that they have not been edited. 

Sorry if I got you wrong! Greetings

Comment: Yes that is the reason because I gave you the second option. In my case my requests are not very compromising and I have a servlet which filters everything, plus another security checks. So, as far as I can see, security is a big plus for you, what do you think about mix solution? IF the user does not have access to some fields instead of hiding disable them, and in the server process the edited fields according level security constraints?

Comment: That is exactly what my question is about: RequestFactory sets the values of the entity before the server method is executed. So there is no way to decide if the user has the permissions and depending on that set the fields or do not. The only way I know of is to secure setters with checks or e.g. spring's @PreAuthorize. That way I would get an exception if the user must not change values but I would need to secure every setter with many authorities to handle all cases. 

And disabling or hiding ui fields does not make any difference at all, it is just useless to protect against abuse...

Comment: Are you using your entities as EntityProxy? We are using ValueProxy and we can control that..., if you introduce Spring in the game, I get lost (not fan of it), but in terms of GWT, using ValueProxies, you can control the update process of an entity.

Comment: You mean that you do not have EntityProxy for a given entity and use ValueProxy instead? So you are fetching an Entity from the database, transform it to a Value Object and pass it to the client and vice versa? Yes, that would do the job for me I guess but I'm afraid my boss won't be happy to refactor hundreds of entities :) 

thanks for your time!

Comment: Yes that is the reason because we are going to move to REST. RequestFactory is quite useful, but it requires a lot of attention (many small things to take care). Good luck! And if you find a solution email it me! :D